# What are the most common username-based password patterns?

Tags: passwords, statistics

I know that there are some common passwords like `hunter6` or `Password`. These are very insecure since everybody knows to try them first.

It is commonly thought that passwords derived from the username alone are also insecure. For instance, setting the password to the same as the username is often accepted a bad idea. Simple functions (eg the username backwards) would in theory also offer little added security - is there any research on which such functions for deriving a password based on the username are the most common?

Comment: You reminded me that Jeff Atwood made [some password stats in the past](https://blog.codinghorror.com/dictionary-attacks-101/), that probably includes a lot of SO/SE passwords.

Answer (score 3):

Username + Current Year

Username + Digit (any of 0-9)

Username + 123

Those are my top 3 determined from a 4000 stations login surveys in a large company.

Comment: And if the policy requires special characters, they will use a "!" as suffix.

Comment: Affirmative, or "*". But only the ones that understand that you have to press shift to type what's above the KB numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Password security depends on how easy it is to guess. You can assign entropy to a password by doing some calculations technically a password *123456* is as good as *612435* just based on how many combinations with that alphabet exist. The only reason *123456* is less secure is due to psychological reasons: More people choose *123456* and attackers guess *123456* first.

The username/password patterns are mostly the same as common word patterns such as:

```
word, [ digit ] # Mostly either current year as 4 or 2 digits
                # But also just single digits or things like 321, 123

word, [ special character ] # Mostly underscores, question marks
                            # exclamation marks

digit, word     # Such as prefixing a word with a 0
```

Comment: If you were to answer my question analytically, you'd need an equation for "entropy given certain information", the certain information being username plus choice of function.

Comment: Entropy is just the log2 of the password space.